# Python Basic Understanding

Tags: python-3.x

The last few weeks I started learning Python (from Python Institute). I'm pretty new on programming so I might be missing something.

I'm on the step where a Python file is on different directory from the module file and try to import it by adding its path to `sys.path`. Location of the files are as follow:
[Files Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y5Tg.png)

Although, I don't think is relevant here is the code of the module:

```
# module.py

#!/usr/bin/env python3 

""" module.py - an example of Python module """

__counter = 0

def suml(list):
    global __counter
    __counter += 1
    sum = 0
    for el in list:
        sum += el
    return sum

def prodl(list):
    global __counter    
    __counter += 1
    prod = 1
    for el in list:
        prod *= el
    return prod

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("I prefer to be a module, but I can do some tests for you")
    l = [i+1 for i in range(5)]
    print(suml(l) == 15)
    print(prodl(l) == 120)
```

And here is the code is supposed to work:

```
# main.py

from sys import path

path.append('..\\modules')

import module

zeroes = [0 for i in range(5)] ones = [1 for i in range(5)] print(module.suml(zeroes)) print(module.prodl(ones))
```

They suggest to append a relative path. I'm using Visual Studio Code on Win 10 home edition.

When I run the code without debugging the code successfully importing the module. When I run the file in Terminal I get a traceback error. I haven't really done reading on how to use the Visual Studio (so far I just follow the chapters) so I'm probably missing something.

Can someone explain if the code I use above is correct and why I get an error when I run the file in Terminal?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you have a relative path in your debug configuration launch.json file (located in your workspace .vscode directory).

In the example below, the program attribute has a relative path to app.js at the root of the workspace (project folder).

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "program": "./app.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

The fix is to use an absolute path or better use the `${workspaceFolder}` variable which will resolve to the absolute path of the project folder.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

By using the `${workspaceFolder}` variable, you won't need to update the absolute path if the project is moved or shared with other developers.